# How to draw multiple PR curves to one chart for PyTorch TensorBoard?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensorboard

Below is the code drawing PR curves taken from https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/tensorboard_tutorial.html#assessing-trained-models-with-tensorboard

```
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter


writer = SummaryWriter()

def add_pr_curve_tensorboard(class_index, test_probs, test_preds):
    tensorboard_preds = test_preds == class_index
    tensorboard_probs = test_probs[:, class_index]

    writer.add_pr_curve(classes[class_index],
                        tensorboard_preds,
                        tensorboard_probs,
                        global_step=0)
    writer.close()


for i in range(len(classes)):
    add_pr_curve_tensorboard(i, test_probs, test_preds)
```

I thought if I change the first parameter `tag` to same value `'all_pr_curves'`, it would help draw all PR curves on same chart.

```
writer.add_pr_curve(
    'all_pr_curves',
    tensorboard_preds,
    tensorboard_probs,
    global_step=0)
```

But it turns out the later one will overwrite the previous one. So at the end, only the last PR curve shows.

Is there a way to draw all PR curves on same chart?